# Using Cognito JavaScript SDK without AWS-SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js

I'm using the Amazon's JavaScript `AWS-SDK` to set the region and credentials for me to use Cognito on my client application. The problem is that the AWS-SDK is huge! Is there a way to import only what I need or not importing anything from the `AWS-SDK` at all?

Here is my code:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk/global'


AWS.config.region = region
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: IdentityPoolId
})
```

Comment: Have you tried to [customize the SDK](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/) for your needs?  You can trim it down to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

From [the Cognito SDK docs](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js):

> The Amazon Cognito Identity SDK for JavaScript depends on:
>
> The `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider` service from the AWS SDK for
>   JavaScript

So you can't use it without the regular AWS SDK for JavaScript. However on that same page it tells you how to create a slimmed down version of the AWS SDK that only includes the needed Cognito dependencies. It also provides a direct link to a slimmed down version ready to use (but with a different namespace). I would recommend going [here](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/) to download a custom version of the SDK that only includes the pieces you need.

Answer (score 1):

There are specialized versions of the AWS SDK just for Cognito and you can build the AWS SDK just for the services that you require.

Here is an example just for Cognito:

[Cognito Identity SDK](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js)

Here is the link to build your own custom AWS SDK:

[AWS SDK for JavaScript in the Browser](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/)

I recommend customizing the official JavaScript SDK and not using specialized versions as the APIs and use cases can be different or limited in functionality.

There is a third option which is to not use the AWS SDKs at all and code everything by hand. This is definitely for experts as you have to deal directly with the REST API, creating signatures, etc.

A Google search will turn up lots of variants of the Cognito SDK.